# how to change values in data frame based on list of column names

Tags: r

I have a data frame and list of columns as below,i am trying to change the value base on my list of column names
i.e if the columns in my df matched with list of columns and in those columns if value is >1 then make those values to 1 else the same values

```
grp = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
value_1 =c(10,21,33,31,423,132,245)
value_2 = c(0,0,NA,1.5,1.75,1,NA)
value_3 = c(10,30,NA,1.0,1.3,1.4,50)
value_4 = c(0,0,NA,1.5,1.75,1,NA)
value_5 = c(1,1.25,0,1.5,0,NA,0)

df =  data.frame(grp,value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4,value_5)

lis = c('value_2','value_4','value_5')
```

to get the desired_df i am trying with the following code

```
df1 = df %>%
          mutate(lis = ifelse(names(df) >1,1,names(df)))
```

help me to get the output as follows

```
grp_1   value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5
A         10     0        10       0    1
A         21     0        30       0    1
A         33    NA       NA       NA    0
A         31    1        1         1    1
A        423    1        1         1    0
A         132   1        1         1    NA
A         245   NA      50        NA    0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you need `df %>% mutate_at(lis, funs(ifelse(.> 1, 1, .)))`

Comment: Also of interest would be `df[lis] <- lapply(df[lis], function(x) replace(x, list = x > 1, 1)); df`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `ifelse`, you can also consider `replace`, which is basically `vector[index] <- values`.

In a real-world application, you could then do:

```
df[lis] <- lapply(df[lis], function(x) replace(x, x > 1, 1))
# Or
# df[lis] <- lapply(df[lis], function(x) { x[x > 1] <- 1; x})
df
#   grp value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5
# 1   A      10       0    10.0       0       1
# 2   A      21       0    30.0       0       1
# 3   A      33      NA      NA      NA       0
# 4   A      31       1     1.0       1       1
# 5   A     423       1     1.3       1       0
# 6   A     132       1     1.4       1      NA
# 7   A     245      NA    50.0      NA       0
```

Using the same logic, you can do the following with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (lis) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[x > 1] <- 1; x}), .SDcols = lis][]
#    grp value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5
# 1:   A      10       0    10.0       0       1
# 2:   A      21       0    30.0       0       1
# 3:   A      33      NA      NA      NA       0
# 4:   A      31       1     1.0       1       1
# 5:   A     423       1     1.3       1       0
# 6:   A     132       1     1.4       1      NA
# 7:   A     245      NA    50.0      NA       0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mutate_at` to specify the column names stored in the 'list' object and within the `funs` apply the function of interest to `mutate` those columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(lis, funs(ifelse(.> 1, 1, .)))
```